# $f_1(x)=sin(x),\; f_{n+1}(x)=sin(f_n(x))$, $(f_n)$ converges to zero uniformly

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

Consider for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the function $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $$f_1(x)=sin(x),\; f_{n+1}(x)=sin(f_n(x)).$$

I'm stuck to prove that $(f_n)_n$ converges to $f=0$ uniformly.

First of all, $(f_n)_n$ converges to $f=0$ uniformly means $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f_n(x)-0|\to 0$ für $n\to\infty$. I know that $|sin(f_n(x))|< |x|$ for all nonzero $x\in\mathbb{R}$, does this estimation help? Furthermore I found this answer [Given the sequence of functions, $f_1(x):=\sin(x)$ and $f_{n+1}(x):=\sin(f_n(x))$, why $|f_n(x)|\leq f_n(1)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650757/given-the-sequence-of-functions-f-1x-sinx-and-f-n1x-sinf-nx) but I don't know, how it helps..
I don't know how to continue.

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

You have $-1 \leq f_1(x) \leq 1$.

Prove by induction that 
$$ | f_n(x) | \leq \sin(\sin (\sin(...(\sin(1)))))$$

**Hint 2**

Prove that the sequence $f_n(1)=\sin(\sin (\sin(...(\sin(1)))))$ is decreasing and bounded. Deduce that it is convergent to a limit $l$ which satisfies 
$$\sin(l)=l$$

Which is the only real number which satisfies this relation?

Comment: thanks, it helps a lot! With your hints everything is clear now. It must be $l=0$ and from this I know how to prove that $(f_n)$ converges to zero uniformly.